Proof that the cartesian product of two countable sets is countable.
I want to show the statement in the title, assuming that it has already been shown that countable unions of countable sets are countable.
Let $M,N$ be countably infinite sets. There exist bijections $\varphi: \mathbb{N} \to M$ and $\psi: \mathbb{N} \to N$.
Claim. $M \times N = \bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}(\bigcup_{l \in \mathbb{N}} \{\varphi(k)\} \times \{\psi(l)\}) =: L$.
Proof. It's clear by definition that every element in $L$ is a tuple with first component in $M$ and second component in $N$ and therefore an element of $M \times N$.
Let $x$ be an element of $M \times N$. Then $x = (m,n)$ for some $m \in M$ and $n \in N$. By bijectivity of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ we get $m = \varphi(i)$ for some $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n = \psi(j)$ for some $j \in \mathbb{N}$. We see
$$x = (\varphi(i),\psi(j)) \in \{\varphi(i)\} \times \{\psi(j)\} \subset \bigcup_{l \in \mathbb{N}} \{\varphi(i)\} \times \{\psi(l)\} \subset \bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\Bigl (\bigcup_{l \in \mathbb{N}} \{\varphi(k)\} \times \{\psi(l)\} \Bigr) = L$$
Claim. $L$ is a countable union of countable sets.
Proof. Fix $k \in \mathbb{N}$. It's true that $\{\varphi(k)\} \times \{\psi(l)\}$ is finite for all $l \in \mathbb{N}$, therefore $\bigcup_{l \in \mathbb{N}} \{\varphi(k)\} \times \{\psi(l)\}$ is countable as a countable union of finite sets. It follows that $L$ is a countable set as a countable union of countable sets.
Would appreciate verification of this proof. I have not seen it before and it seems simpler to me then invoking prime factorization for example. I'm worried there might be some circularity with using the "countable unions of countable sets are countable" as given? Does this proof hold?

Your proof shows that the cartesian product of countably infinite sets is countable (not quite the same as your title). If you wanted to show the cartesian product of countably infinite sets is countably infinite (again, not quite the same) you need to show $M \times N$ is infinite, which is easy to do. If you wanted to show the cartesian product of countable sets is countable, you can modify your proof as we know, for example, there is a $\varphi$ which is a injection between $M$ and $\omega$ and therefore a bijection between $M$ and ran $\varphi$ and ran $\varphi$ is a subset of $\omega$ and therefore countable. And so $\varphi^{-1}$ is a bijection between ran $\varphi$ and $M$. Other than that, I believe your proof is OK.
However, the proof relies on the result that the countable union of countable sets is countable, and for this you need choice, and so your proof is relying on choice.
But there is a proof (assuming the version in your title, but other versions are provable in a similar way) which does not use choice (which might be the reason that the version in your proof is not that common):
If $A,B$ are countable then there exist 1-1 functions $f,g$ such that $f:A 
 \rightarrow \omega $ and $g:B \rightarrow \omega$. Define $h$ on $\omega \times \omega$ by $h:<x,y> \mapsto 2^x3^y$. Then $h:\omega \times \omega \rightarrow \omega$ and it is not too hard to show $h$ is 1-1. Define $l$ on $A \times B$ by $l:<x,y> \mapsto <f(x),g(y)>$. Then $l:A \times B \rightarrow \omega \times \omega$ and again we can show $l$ is 1-1 and so $h \circ l:A \times B \rightarrow \omega$ is 1-1 and so $A \times B$ is countable.
